# Is there any way to remove an element from the dom with visbility:hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am buidling a header/navbar that changes as you scroll down. I would like icons to smoothly transiton from hamburger menu to sun/moon the issue is that if I use display:none; I changes quickly and transition on opacity is not visible. Just feels very jerky, visiblity: hidden works but then the icons do not align center.. Any ideas how I could go about it ?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8kTv.png)

https://codepen.io/senche/pen/wvQoReb

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <ul class="">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Charity Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </ul></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="hamburger hidden"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></div>
     <button id="dark-mode-toggle" class="dark-mode" area-label="toggle dark mode">
          <i class="bx bx-moon moon" id="moon"></i>
          <i class="bx bx-sun sun" id="sun"></i>
        </button>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}


body {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
 
  height: 100vh;
}

.left { 
transition:all 1s ease;
}

ul {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 65px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  top:50px;
  transition:all 1s ease;
}
ul li {
  width: 160px;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;

  text-align: center;
  color: #5e5e62;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
ul li.active a {
  background-image: linear-gradient(117deg, #838386, #26262a);
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

ul li:nth-child(1).active ~ .slide {
  left: -1px;
  opacity: 1;
}
ul li:nth-child(2).active ~ .slide {
  left: 153px;
  opacity: 1;
}
ul li:nth-child(3).active ~ .slide {
  left: 314px;
  opacity: 1;
}
ul li:nth-child(4).active ~ .slide {
  left: 472px;
  opacity: 1;
}
ul li:nth-child(5).active ~ .slide {
  left: 630px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.right { 
display:flex;
box-shadow: 0 9px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  border-radius:50%;
    width: 65px;
  height:65px;

  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.hamburger {

  color:pink;

font-size:1.6rem;

}



#dark-mode-toggle {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 1s ease;

}

#moon {
  color: var(--p-clr);
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: block;
}

.darkmode #moon {
  display: none;
}

#sun {
  color: var(--p-clr);
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: none;
}

.darkmode #sun {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {

 visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");
const sun = document.getElementById("sun");
const moon = document.getElementById("moon");
const darkModeToggle = document.querySelector(".dark-mode");


li.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    ul.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");

    el.classList.add("active");
  });
});



const enableDarkMode = () => {
  document.documentElement.classList.add("darkmode");
  localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "enabled");
};

const disableDarkMode = () => {
  document.documentElement.classList.remove("darkmode");
  localStorage.setItem("darkMode", null);
};

darkModeToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");

  if (darkMode !== "enabled") {
    enableDarkMode();
  } else {
    disableDarkMode();
  }
});



window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
 scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

  console.log(scrollPosition)
 if (scrollPosition > 100) {

hamburger.classList.remove("hidden");
ul.classList.add("hidden");
 darkModeToggle.classList.add("hidden");

   
 } else if (scrollPosition < 100){
ul.classList.remove("hidden");
hamburger.classList.add("hidden");
 darkModeToggle.classList.remove("hidden");

 }
});
```

Comment: use z-index and opacity; z-index maybe not a must, but opacity is the way to go